# Civilized aliens coming from Mars in spaceships to build the pyramids

Tags: internal-consistency, aliens, planets, pyramids

I'm writing a classic Mars-pyramid story in which some Martian aliens ride in a spaceship and come to Earth and build the Egyptian pyramids. Their environment on Mars is very dry, there are no rivers--there used to be rivers but they dried up and now they're digging very deep wells to get groundwater--but there's lots of stone (that's what the Egyptian pyramids are *really* made of). They eat Martian plants, which are all blue. The aliens have already put up satellites around the Earth (they're high-tech aliens) and they've seen what the Earth is like. They see that there are lush rainforests, rivers, and green plants. They like it so they come to Earth and they land in Egypt. Actually, they originally didn't want to land in Egypt; they wanted to land in the Nile Delta, but their spaceship's camera failed and they didn't have something like GPS, so they could only randomly land. They landed in the eastern desert of Egypt and they see that it isn't like what they thought Earth was. Now, they're lost. They go back into the spaceship and see if there's anything to help them get to where they wanted to go, and after hours of searching, the captain finds a drone with a camera. They hop back into the spaceship and use the drones to navigate, and they get to where they wanted to go. So, they settle down somewhere here that hasn't previously been settled by humans.

However, one day, they decide to conquer Egypt since their colony on Egypt has run out of resources and they don't want to go back to Mars. However, their colony doesn't have enough military strength to defeat the Egyptians, so they send a group in the colony back to Mars to get military reinforcements; these aliens are okay with just going back to Mars to get military reinforcements, but they wouldn't be fine with returning to Mars and settling in Mars again. They conquer Egypt, and they decide to build a big pyramid as a monument to record their conquest of Egypt.

So, what could the alien's technology look like? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! I think you accidentally pressed "Submit" too early. Would you be able to edit your question to finish whatever it was you were going to ask?

Comment: @F1Krazy Oops, thanks! I accidentally pressed the "Submit" button and at that time I had forgotten that I hadn't finished writing the content of the question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I wondered if your query didn't get shut down by some military conspiracy or other.  Anyway, I think you're going to want to edit your question again: in what way is the answer "sure, why not?" If the Barsoomians have space ships that are capable of getting their people from Barsoom to Jasoom and back, why couldn't they just build some pyramids whilst here?  Take a look at our [tour] and [help] and [what Worldbuilding is all about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about); edit your question to focus on a specific...

Comment: (cont) ... issue, rather than a broad scope query. You might also consider telling us a little about your Barsoomians' worldview: why would they consider such a project, and what would make it necessary for them to accomplish this? E.g., Earth folks are natively curious: humans would go to Mars just because it's there (and if looked all blue and green and inviting, all the more so!) So what are their motivations?

Comment: @elemtilas I've finished editing the question. Thanks!

Comment: Okay! Now, focus on the nature of your question itself. It's looking like you are asking about the motivations and actions of characters: the captain decides this, the people do that. This is what we'd call "story writing" rather than "world building", and this is going to get your question put on hold pretty quick! My suggestion would be to refocus on cultural, historical and social foundations. Ask about the people themselves, rather than about the plot-line choices they make. Basically, this it not a forum for asking about storycraft; we're here to help you with your fictional world itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let me get this straight, do the aliens land in Egypt because they like the green plants, rivers, and jungles?

[image: Egyptian pyramids]

This Egypt ?

Since we are dealing with aliens, we cant really say for sure if it doesn't make sense. Humans like to build monuments and put up statues of slave owners or war criminals so I guess pyramids can't be out of the question.

If triangles or the shape itself has any deeper meaning in there society, building one would totally make sense. And even if it isn't so, there's still reason to build a pyramid since the shape itself is very stable. I mean, look at the real ones. They have been standing around for over 4,000 years and still look pretty decent. So if an alien race would want to build something on earth that they don't have to constantly maintain, a pyramid might be a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I'd like to add some historical notes on the ancient Egyptians. The Egyptians didn't think of the pyramid shape as magical or whatever; pyramids actually grew out of tombs for pharaohs called *mastaba*s. Mastabas were bench-like structures. However, one pharaoh decided to stack mastabas that were progressively smaller as they went higher. This was called the "Step Pyramid." Another pharaoh came along and decided to make it into a pyramid shape, maybe because he didn't like the look of a step pyramid.

Comment: However, in the story, we can say that the aliens liked the pyramid shape so they built a pyramid. P.S. What "*joke*"? I don't understand. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: I always thought the Egyptians wanted to build something that lasts and can be very big. It dosnt take a Genius to figure out that a Pyramid can be as tall as you want it to be. As long as the base grows too of course. 

The joke was that you said the Aliens liked the not waste land of the Earth, and then they land in the Desert. The one place that looks like Mars.

Comment: Actually, in my story, when I talked about the aliens landing in the desert, the reason for this is actually that the aliens' spaceship partially broke and they could only land randomly. Of course they wouldn't have wanted to land in the desert. They're supposed to accidentally land in the desert. I'll add that into the question body. Thanks! P.S. About the ancient Egyptians: They didn't terribly like the pyramid shape, but they wanted to build a lasting monument to show other cultures their power and strength, and that they had enough manpower to build a pyramid that was just a tomb.

Comment: The Aliens must have had one hell of a conversation: "SO WE SPEND 10 MONTHS IN SPACE IN A CRANKED ROOM ONLY TO CRASHLAND IN THE FUCKING DESERT !?"

Comment: The aliens start shouting and screaming to the captain, and then the captain tells them "Calm down. We'll find a way to get to where we wanted to go." Unless one of them starts saying "I'm going back to Mars. I'm not staying on this planet called Earth."

Comment: I've accepted your answer. Thanks!